# Netsuite suiteQL get fields of tables and fields of views

Tags: odbc, netsuite, suiteql

How can I get a list of fields for tables or views from NetSuite using a SuiteQL connection?

I tried `select * from oa_columns where table_name = 'account';` but that did not work.

I'm using the CDATA ODBC Connector

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ColumnName FROM sys_tablecolumns WHERE TableName='Account'` does the trick

Comment: NetSuite gives me an "Invalid search type" error for this